# How may devices [ iPhone] can be bonded with single Peripherals [ Bluetooth Low Energy Devices]

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Having looked upon the CoreBluetooth V4, not sure if i have missed to get the standard information about how may observers [ my case iPhone] can be bonded with single Bluetooth Low Energy Device?.

If peripheral could able to bond with multiple observers, then could it not be considered as a security issue ?

Kindly provide suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A peripheral device (the observed) can only have a single connection at a time. The number of devices that it can bond with depends on the HW and SW of the peripheral. A central device could even configure the peripheral to broadcast e.g. through advertising, rather than through a connection, to multiple listening devices.

Security and authorisation are required for bonding, what kind of security issue were you thinking of?

Here is an interesting use case:
1000+ runners at a marathon, say only ~10% have Bluetooth Smart sensors in their running shoes and a smart phone app to link to them. If a single user tries to poll for a connection to his shoe sensors, how is he going to identify them from the, potentially hundreds, of shoe sensors present in the environment?

;)

Comment: Pev, Thanks for the reply. A peripheral device can only have a single connection at a time. Now, lets say my shoe sensor i have bonded with my iPhone, and now i am using it. Next day my friend want to use the same shoe sensor to bond his device. Is that allowed?

Comment: Should be. They would have to bond with it e.g. authenticate the connection.

Comment: Where i can see which standard says about this?. Bluetooth Core specification V4 ?.

Comment: Downvote reason : peripheral can handle many many central connection at the same time - the amount of connections you can see in datasheet. For example Bluetooth Giga 113 supports up to 8 LE connections https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble113-bluetooth--smart-module/technical-specs/

Comment: Then it is not compliant with the BlueTooth Specification - Core 4.1 [Vol 1], Section 6.2 General Access Profile, states:The Peripheral
role is optimized for devices that support a single connection and are less complex than central devices. Devices supporting the peripheral role only require Controllers that support the Controller’s slave role. The Central role supports multiple connections and is the initiator for all connections with
devices in the peripheral role.